# How can I manage my API endpoint for an entity that has other related entities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a RESTful API with Spring.
I am reading the docs and tutorials and most of them have just basic objects in their examples and I don't know how to combine all that into solving my current problem...

I don't know how to handle 2 things here:

1. What is the best way to handle the creation of my entity with an HTTP request? Should I send the IDs of the related entities in the body, in the query params? Should I just send the entire object?
2. In this case, if I send the IDs of the related entities separately, I believe the `@Valid` annotation
   would trigger as invalid because the body would not have the objects
   the model asks for (`Employee` and `Customer`, in my case).

This is the endpoint:

```
    @PostMapping("/orders")
    ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Order>> createOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Order order) {
        order.setStatus(Status.IN_PROGRESS);
        Order newOrder = repository.save(order);

        return ResponseEntity
            .created(linkTo(methodOn(OrderController.class).getOrder(newOrder.getId())).toUri())
            .body(assembler.toModel(newOrder));
    }
```

The entity I want to create and validate:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String description;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private Status status;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "employee_id_fk"))
    private Employee employee;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "customer_id_fk"))
    private Customer customer;

    protected Order() {}

    public Order(String description) {
        this.description = description;
        this.status = Status.IN_PROGRESS;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to handle the creation of my entity with an HTTP
> request? Should I send the IDs in the body, in the query params?
> Should I just send the entire object?

When we create a new record in the database, we don't send the Id in the request, Id will be generated automatically based on *strategy* defined in `@GeneratedValue` when you save the entity using `orderRepository.save(order);` You just need to pass the object with the required details that you want to save.

The ideal way to receive the payload for `@RequesetBody` is by using the *DTOs*. We may create the DTOs according to the requirements and can specify the Ids of type Long or required instead of using the whole Object such as `Customer` and `Employee`

```
public class OrderDTO {

    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String description;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private Status status;

    @NotNull
    private Long employeeId;

    @NotNull
    private Long customerId;

    protected Order() {}

    public Order(...) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Request payload will be:

```
{
    "id" : null,
    "description" : "payload using DTO",
    "status" : "yourStatus",
    "employeeId" : 1,
    "customerId" : 2
}
```

> In this case, if I send the IDs separately, I believe the @Valid
> annotation would trigger as invalid because the body would not have
> the objects the model asks for (Employee and Customer, in my case)

`@Valid` validated the constraints which we have specified for modal/DTO used in `@RequestBody`

Comment: I apologize: I did not mean the id of Order, but the id of Employee and Customer. I just edited the question to make it more clear!

Comment: Thanks, @ManuCarba I have updated the answer accordingly.